# Regular expression, string not ends with specific symbols

Tags: regex

So basically what I'm doing is so: I have some text and I need to get urls from it. This is the exact regexp I'm using:

```
http(s)?://([\w-]+\.[\w-]+)([/\.[\w-]+])*([a-zA-Z0-9\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&amp;\*\(\)_\-\=\+\\\/\?\.\:\;\'\,]*)?
```

The problem is it also matches such urls as **http:// ex.ample&quot;** and so on. I need only **http:// ex.ample** part.

So I need to update regex in such way that urls couldn't end with following characters:

```
."()'<>;
```

AND not with one of the following sequences of characters:

```
&quot;
&#39;
&nbsp;
&gt;
&lt;
```

I'm stuck with it for like 2 days. Thanks!

Comment: Which regex engine are you using?

Comment: Also, why would you need to check for all these entities if strings ending in `;` aren't allowed anyway?

Comment: @TimPietzcker I don't check if string is allowed or not. Edited the post to show what I'm doing exactly.

Comment: That is a *completely* different problem from what you first asked.

Comment: Any luck on the suggested regex?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the following would suffice:

```
^.*(?<![."()'<>;])$
```

Since a `;` is already forbidden as the last character, all the entities you mentioned will be excluded too. See it at [rubular.com](http://rubular.com/r/f3rbYDT3N8).

**Explanation:**

`(?<![."()'<>;])` checks that it's impossible to match any of the characters `."()'<>;` before the current position (which is guaranteed to be the end of string, thanks to the `$` [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).

If you happen to be stuck with JavaScript (which doesn't support [lookbehind assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)), use

```
^(?:.*[^."()'<>;])?$
```

This matches either the empty string or a string of 1 or more characters, the last of which is not one of `."()'<>;`; I'm using a negated [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to ensure that.

Comment: Nice thinking, I like it.

Comment: Thanks for help, but I need to exclude exactly '&quote;' and others if string ends with them and the problem is if I write something like this `[^;](?!quote;)` than **asd&quote**; matches. I don't need it.

Comment: @KonstantinVasilev: Did you actually test my regex? It already works as is. Or is `;` allowed as a final character after all?

Comment: @TimPietzcker yes, using it on string _asd&quot;_ result match is **asd&quot**, but I need only **asd**